# Does Svelte support checkbox binding?

Tags: svelte

Does Svelte support bindings for checkboxes?

I am aware that the documentation says the following, so it is possible that it has yet to be implemented.

> Two-way binding is not yet fully implemented. Check back soon for the full list of available bindings!

I imagine that the implementation would look something like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" bind:checked="checked">
```

However, when I try this at the moment, it does not seem to work.

**Update**

Upon further investigation, it seems that the binding is working in some way, with the bound value changing in the component data. However, for some reason, changes are not being reflected in the DOM. They can be reflected by simply setting the data to be itself (`component.set({checked: component.get('checked')})`), forcing a DOM update, but they are not being reflected automatically, as they should with binding.

**Update 2**

I have [created a REPL](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.25.0&gist=8549bef0970e292050621e38c724e76f) to demonstrate this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you need to bind the *component* as well as the `<input>` element:

```html
<Component bind:checked="checked"></Component>
```

You can see it working [here](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.7.1&gist=34d33258e444c37bcfd827ad9b2f7b42).

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. This did not cross my mind, as I was under the impression that data properties were already bound together once they had been passed from a parent component to a child component. Is it that there is a one-way binding from the parent component to the child component in this case, and that `:bind` declares a two-way binding between the parent and the child?

Comment: That's exactly right, yes — it's designed that way so that unidirectional data flow is the default, and two-way binding is opt-in (since it can cause nasty mutation bugs if done blindly)

Comment: I tried the linked example but it says "Could not load ./App.html: O is not a function"

Comment: @poshaughnessy try the updated link (it was using an older version of Svelte, with an out of date syntax)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with

```
<script>
     let checked = false;
</script>


<input type=checkbox bind:checked={checked}>
```

Now the variable `checked` is bound to the value of checkbox.

You can try this in [this neat little example](https://svelte.dev/examples#checkbox-inputs)